# Finding children that meet a specefic criteria in ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have two tables :
The first one is named `sales` and has two columns named `product` and `quantity`
The second one is named `nomenclature` and has two columns named `compound` and `component`.

Every `compound` can have several `components` and every `component` can be itself a `compound` with several `components` which makes the second table a hierarchy.
Let's take for example the following tables :

```
TABLE : SALES
PRODUCT  -  QUANTITY
    P1       -  200
    P2       -  300
    F3       -  400
    P5       -  500


TABLE : NOMENCLATURE
COMPOUND - COMPONENT
P1        - A1
P1        - B2
P2        - D4
A1        - F6
B2        - Q7
D4        - F8
Q7        - F9
F9        - H10
P3        - F11
```

I want to find for every row in `SALES.PRODUCT` every component in its hierarchy that starts with F and return them and/or return itself if the product itself starts with F or ignore the row otherwise. The final result should look like this :

```
PRODUCT - QUANTITY - COMPONENT
P1      - 200      - F6
P1      - 200      - F9
P2      - 300      - F8
F3      - 400      - F3
F3      - 400      - F11
```

(P5 is ignored since it doesn't start with F and doesn't have any children that start with F)

How to do obtain this result in PL/SQL (ORACLE) with the most efficient way (NOMENCLATURE actually has over 500k rows)

Comment: What have you tried so far? And are you sure you mean PL/SQL and not simply SQL?

Comment: How do you get the last two lines of the output? `F11` is paired with `P3` not `F3` and there is no `F3` component.

Comment: Can you try and have your example output reflect on the example tables you gave us?  This will help better relate the tables.  Are you saying the product is a compound?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
WITH combined ( product, component, quantity ) AS (
  SELECT product, product, quantity FROM sales
UNION ALL
  SELECT compound, component, NULL FROM nomenclature
)
SELECT CONNECT_BY_ROOT( product ) AS product,
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT( quantity ) AS quantity,
       component
FROM   combined
WHERE  component LIKE 'F%'
START WITH quantity IS NOT NULL
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR component = product;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly ! I swapped the columns names "component" and "compound" in the question to make it more "literately" accurate. Please swap component and compound in the second "SELECT" to make it reflect the changes I made and add a parenthesis after "AS" so I can mark the question resolved.

Comment: @IlyesFerchiou Updated